# Order of execution for Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, timeout

I am reading 
[this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Timing)
 about Promises and I don't understand something.

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

wait().then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));
console.log(1);
```

There is this example which outputs `1 2 3 4`.

So, it is normal that `1` is printed first, but why is `2 3` next and not `4`? 
They are both inside a `then()`, `4` is inside a `setTimeout` but it has no milliseconds passed as parameter.

Comment: Short answer will be that, `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));` is actually executed before the `setTimeout` as it executed in the so called “microtask queue” instead of the "callback queue".

Comment: Regarding the "it has no milliseconds passed as parameter." when you don't specify ms or set it to 0 in the `setTimeout` function it actually has default minimum, which is  differ by each browser

Comment: @Konrud really? It has a minimum?

Comment: Yes, Timeouts throttled to ≥ 4ms.
 For more info read this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout  (under this title `Reasons for delays longer than specified`)

Comment: Fascinating. However, I think that there's some extra conditions in the link you gave: it only throttles it to 4ms after a certain number of settimeouts have been queued, if I'm reading it correctly. `calls are throttled to a minimum of once every 4 ms when successive calls are triggered due to callback nesting (where the nesting level is at least a certain depth), or after certain number of successive intervals.`

Comment: @TKoL what I meant is under the **NOTE** messages:  `The minimum delay, DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE, is 4 ms....`

Comment: ah I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout` is the entire reason. Try this in contrast:

```
const wait2 = ms => new Promise(resolve => resolve());

wait2().then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));
console.log(1);
```

Where the `wait` function resolves with no timeout. This does what you expect, 1423

Even if you don't pass a number to `setTimeout`, the javascript interpreter will wait until the processing queue is cleared before before running the contents of a `setTimeout`